# I can't start fastlane iOS build. gym ends up with error

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane

Hi I'm trying to get a build for TestFlight. I configured all certificates, git repo properly but it doesn't works anyway. I can run build on xCode and on simulator or cable connected device. But I can't get ipa file to publish. To be honest I couldn't even understand what is the error

My Fastfile

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

    desc 'Fetch certificates and provisioning profiles'
    lane :certificates do
      match(
        readonly: true
      )
    end

desc 'Fetch code signing secrets. Build the iOS application.'
lane :build do
    certificates
    # Creates a signed file
    gym(
        export_method: "app-store",
    )
end

desc "Upload to TestFlight"
lane :beta do
    # Using default env variable names for fastlane to pick them up. 
    app_store_connect_api_key(
        is_key_content_base64: true,
    )
    pilot
end


end
```

The error log from fastlane iOS build

````
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ./NativeNfcFastConfig.xcworkspace -scheme NativeNfcFastConfig -destination generic/platform=iOS -archivePath "/Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-02-09/NativeNfcFastConfig 2023-02-09 12.24.02.xcarchive" archive

User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-02-09/NativeNfcFastConfig 2023-02-09 12.24.02.xcarchive
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs

Create build description
Build description signature: 4d3e133bf8ba6d1198922adad77059ec
Build description path: /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XCBuildData/4d3e133bf8ba6d1198922adad77059ec-desc.xcbuild

note: Building targets in dependency order
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
    note: Target 'React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
    note: Target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' (project 'Pods') has create directory command with output '/Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NativeNfcFastConfig' from project 'NativeNfcFastConfig')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NativeNfcFastConfig' from project 'NativeNfcFastConfig')
/Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/NativeNfcFastConfig/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: Signing for "React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: unexpected mutating task ('SetOwnerAndGroup deepcontrolmacbookpro:staff /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle') with no relation to prior mutator ('SetOwnerAndGroup deepcontrolmacbookpro:staff /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle') (in target 'React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: unexpected mutating task ('SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle') with no relation to prior mutator ('SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle') (in target 'React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/en.lproj' on task: CpResource /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/en.lproj /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/NativeNfcFastConfig/node_modules/react-native/React/AccessibilityResources/en.lproj (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle' on task: MkDir /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '' on task: MkDir /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/Info.plist' on task: ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/Info.plist /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/NativeNfcFastConfig/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/React-Core/ResourceBundle-AccessibilityResources-React-Core-Info.plist (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '' on task: RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '' on task: SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '' on task: SetOwnerAndGroup deepcontrolmacbookpro:staff /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '' on task: SetOwnerAndGroup deepcontrolmacbookpro:staff /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')
warning: duplicate output file '' on task: Touch /Users/deepcontrolmacbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NativeNfcFastConfig-ewyimnoosnhlyzdsbwwdsbnkcthu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/NativeNfcFastConfig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')```


I tried to check certificates, identifiers and profiles
````

Comment: I had the same error and this link helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66669750/multiple-commands-produce-on-xcode-12-and-react-native